# react prop type validation error

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-proptypes

I have a React component with the following proptypes defined:

```
NavBar.propTypes = {
  navbar: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    brand: PropTypes.shape({
      linkTo: PropTypes.string,
      text: PropTypes.string,
    }),
    links: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      linkTo: PropTypes.string,
      text: PropTypes.string,
      dropdown: PropTypes.bool,
      active: PropTypes.bool,
      links: PropTypes.links,
      eventKey: PropTypes.string,
    })),
  })),
};
```

The props validation given following errors:

```
20:50  error  'navbar.brand.linkTo' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
20:83  error  'navbar.brand.text' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
5:45  error  'linkTo' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
5:60  error  'text' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
6:47  error  'linkTo' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
6:62  error  'text' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
5:7   error  'active' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
6:23  error  'links' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
6:29  error  'links.map' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
17:42  error  'text' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
7:23  error  'links' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
7:29  error  'links.map' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

How should I structure my proptypes to not receive these errors?

Answer (score 2):

`navbar` validation issues:
  You are defining `navbar` as an array but it looks like it is being used as an object.

`linkTo` validation issues:
 You are nesting `linkTo` inside of `navbar.brand`and `navbar.links` in the propsTypes definition yet it looks like you are using it directly as `this.props.linksTo`.

`text` validation issues:
 You are nesting `text` inside of `navbar.brand`and `navbar.links` in the propsTypes definition yet it looks like you are using it directly as `this.props.text`.

`links` validation issues:
 You are nesting `links` inside of `navbar` in the propsTypes definition yet it looks like you are using it directly as `this.props.links`.

`active`validation issue:
 You are defining `active` and not using it.

If you include your component definition, we could offer more insight.